# C# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize to Image

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to receive an image over a TcpClient in C# and I am having troubles deserialize the image and putting it into the picture box on my Windows form, am I missing something obvious or is this not possible at all? I originally made the code in Visual Basic, and now I am trying to transfer it to C#.
Here is my Visual Basic version which works perfectly fine:

```
Private Sub ReceiveImage()

    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    While client.Connected = True
        Try
            ns = client.GetStream
            PictureBox1.Image = bf.Deserialize(ns)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Client disconnected!")
        End Try

    End While

End Sub
```

And my C# Version is this:

```
    public static void ReceiveImage()
    {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        while (client.Connected)
        {

            try
            {
                ns = client.GetStream();
                self.pictureBox1.Image = bf.Deserialize(ns);
                //                          ^Error here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {



            }
        }

    }
```

The full error I get when I hover my mouse over the error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'. An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?`

Comment: Hi @Jimmy, can you post the detail of the exception please.

Comment: @Thomas I've added the error at the bottom of the post. The code isn't throwing any exceptions, just giving me that error.

Comment: did you try to use an explicit cast ? `self.pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)bf.Deserialize(ns);`

Comment: @Thomas That suppresses the error, thank you. I'm not sure why I didn't think of this. Would you like to make an answer so I can confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the object returned by the `BinaryFormatter`:

```
self.pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)bf.Deserialize(ns);
```

If you need explanations about how casting works in C#, you can have a look at this : [Casting and Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).